# getLocalActivityManager not working in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using a class which is extending ActivityGroup and there is a method:

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent);
    if (window != null) {
        mIdList.add(Id);
        setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
    }  
}
```

When debugging in Android 2.2,

```
getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent)
```

is returning null. In 4.0 it's working fine.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read [this note](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html#startActivity%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.Intent%29)?

> Warning: There is an issue where, if the Intent does not include an explicit component, we can restore the state for a different activity class than was previously running when the state was saved (if the set of available activities changes between those points).

This could maybe explain your problem. By the way It seems that you are trying to implement something like fragments. Better use the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) this is a backport for older android versions.